# Regex: findall all substrings in text

Tags: python, regex

I have a long text, it's part of them

```
C: state name of the Company in Russian: [03_SNYuLOOO IC "Story Group".]
). - [04_MNMestablishment of the Company: 107S64, Russian Federation, Moscow, 
ul. Krasnobogatyrskaya, 2, is built.
2, floor 3. com. 11. Office B].
```

I need to findall all substrings like this:

```
[03_SNYuLOOO IC "Story Group".]
[04_MNMestablishment of the Company: 107S64, Russian Federation, Moscow, 
ul. Krasnobogatyrskaya, 2, is built.
2, floor 3. com. 11. Office B]
```

I try to use

```
re.findall(r'^\[\d{2}_[\s\S]+\]$', text)
```

But it returns empty list.
What do I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` and `$` anchors require the whole string to match the pattern and `[\s\S]+` match any 1+ chars as many as possible, grabbing any `[` and `]` on its way to the end of string, so the final `]` will match the rightmost `]` in the string.

You may use the following regex:

```
r'\[\d{2}_[^]]+]'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rEQ91c/1)

**Details**

- `\[`  - a literal `[`
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `[^]]+` - one or more chars other than `]`
- `]` - a literal `]`.

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/DJLV64300):

```
import re
s='''C: state name of the Company in Russian: [03_SNYuLOOO IC "Story Group".]
). - [04_MNMestablishment of the Company: 107S64, Russian Federation, Moscow, 
ul. Krasnobogatyrskaya, 2, is built.
2, floor 3. com. 11. Office B].'''
print(re.findall(r'\[\d{2}_[^]]+]', s))
# => ['[03_SNYuLOOO IC "Story Group".]', '[04_MNMestablishment of the Company: 107S64, Russian Federation, Moscow, \nul. Krasnobogatyrskaya, 2, is built.\n2, floor 3. com. 11. Office B]']
```

Comment: It seems like `re.findall('\[.*?\]', s, flags=re.DOTALL)` would also work?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused as to why `[^]]+` doesn't need an escaped `]` - does the negated set assume there will be at least one character within it?

Comment: @ACascarino If you feel more comfortable with an escaped `]` inside a character set, please do. A `]` at the character set start position is parsed as a literal `]`. If you place any other char between `[` and `]`, `]` will end the character set, you will have to escape it.